# Display Attribute if Price == 0

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-attribute, category-products

I need to display a products attribute if the product price is equal to 0 on a category page on Magento, similar to this post but using price to then display an attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489186/magento-if-attribute-value-is-x-or-y-then-show-custom-block

Comment: Ok, so I have made a little progress, but still need to get this code to then display a products attribute:

<div class="price-box">
                        <?php if ($_product->getFinalPrice() == 0) : ?>
                        <p>Free from <span style="color:green;">ATRRIBUTE TO DISPLAY HERE</span> per month</p>
                        <?php else: ?> 
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code in list.phtml:

```
 <?php 

echo $price = number_format($_product->getPrice(), '2', '.', ',');
 if($price ==0)
 {
   $_product->getYourAttribute();
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: I think you haven't quite got what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @MathewPorter I have updated answer please check it.

Comment: @have you tried this one ??

Comment: Thats just essentially displaying the price if the price == 0.

I need to display the attribute if the products price is == 0

Answer (score 1):

Try following assuming your attribute code is "abc_xyz" and attribute name is "attributename"

```
<div class="price-box">
<?php if ($_product->getFinalPrice() == 0) : ?> 
        <p>Free from <span style="color:green;"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getAbcXyz(), 'attributename') ?></span> per month</p> 
    <?php else: ?> 
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?> 
<?php endif; ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Still not quite there, I think the issue is with the fact that I need the following:  

Show the lowest $tariff_price (attribute that is a text field) that the bundle product price is = 0 at.  

`$childProductIds = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)-  >getChildrenIds($product->getId(), false);  
$TariffPrice = null;  
foreach ($childProductIds as $childProductId) {  
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($childProductId);  
    if ($TariffPrice === null || $product->getPrice() <   $TariffPrice) {  
        $TariffPrice = $product->getPrice();  
    }  
}  
echo $TariffPrice;`

Comment: The above is what I have just tried (it doesn't work anyway), but looking at it I dont think it would quite do what I am trying to achieve anyway.